# Firebase email verification invalid certificate issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am running into a strange error with email link verification on Firebase. When users create an account, I send them the following email and wait for them to verify before continuing normal application flow:

> Hello %DISPLAY_NAME%,
>
> Follow this link to verify your email address.
>
> `https://project-projectname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>`
>
> If you didn’t ask to verify this address, you can ignore this email.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Your ProjectName team

(modified slightly to take out the project name)

This email successfully sends, but when a user clicks on the link in the email they get something to the effect of:

[image: Certificate invalid screenshot]

Which is weird because the link is the default HTTPS link that Firebase gave me to verify email addresses with.

No user can pass beyond this point, and I have tried multiple browsers, multiple devices, multiple email addresses and nobody can verify their email. I have searched everywhere and cannot find anyone with the same issue, so it's very possible I am overlooking something very obvious.

I should note that they used to be able to verify their email successfully - about a week ago it stopped working.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This seems odd indeed, and is not how it's supposed to work. There was an [issue with OAuth responses](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/19001) a few days ago, but that has since been resolved. Are you sure there is no proxy in between your client and the Firebase servers that is modifying the traffic? Can you try on a different network? If that doesn't solve the problem, I'd [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I have the same problem, glad to know I'm not alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I have found a "solution" to this issue!

For reasons I cannot understand, the email verification links will not work on my home WiFi, but if I try the same links using mobile data it works the way it should.

If you are having this error, try using a different form of internet connection and it will probably work!

However, I do not understand why this is the case because my home WiFi has no special Firewalls up or anything out of the ordinary. If someone could explain why this might be happening I would love to know. I will contact Firebase so they at least know that this is happening to some users.

*Thanks for the help @Frank van Puffelen*