# Firebase Auth Connection Not Private

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My app has been working fine for the past few months, but it suddenly started having an issue with signing people in. When you visit https://kentonishi.github.io/gatherapp/# and click the sign in button, it warns me that "Attackers might be trying to steal your information from gatherapp-14b50.firebaseapp.com". Is this a temporary Firebase issue, or did I mess up something?

Comment: I don't get such an error. Would you be able to share a screenshot?

Comment: Does is look similar as in this report? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081131/firebase-email-verification-invalid-certificate-issue

Comment: Yes, and it turns out it was a problem with my firewall. But it seems like firebase changed something, because multiple people have reported the same problem today.